# Как вывести в список массив который пришел вместе с интентом с другой активити?

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-intent

У меня в приложении есть три вида сообщений: черновики, отправленные и полученные. С последними двумя все понятно и просто, но черновики это особый лично для меня вид сообщений. Все потому что эти сообщения можно отредактировать и отправить, тогда это сообщение из категории черновик переходит в категорию отправленное, либо просто отредактировать и сохранить в черновик опять. Но есть сложность с которой я не смог справится - у меня в письмах, независимо от вида могут быть прикрепленные файлы.

У меня есть специальная форма для написания сообщений, и там я могу прикреплять файлы. Все прикрепленные файлы собираются в список и отображаются в форме, и после написания письма, письма перегоняются в массив и отправляются на сервер. При отправке письма все просто и понятно, но я могу сохранить письмо в черновик, и тогда я тоже отправляю на сервер массив прикрепленных файлов. А дальше уже при редактировании черновика я могу удалить полученные прикрепленные файлы и прикрепить новые.

Написал много, но по сути вроде как ничего. В чем у меня проблема - я не могу отобразить полученный с активити просмотра сообщения (в нашем случае черновик) и переданные в форму написания сообщений. У меня там уже есть список и я его хочу загрузить данными с возможностью удаления или добавления элементов списка. Вот как я передаю данный список на форму:

```
case R.id.edit:
Intent intent2 = new Intent(MessageShow.this, WriteResponseMess.class);
switch (mail_type) {
case 3:
intent2.putExtra("theme", theme);
intent2.putExtra("body", body);
intent2.putExtra("kind", mail_type);
break;
case 6:
intent2.putExtra("theme", theme);
intent2.putExtra("body", body);
intent2.putExtra("receiver_mail", name);
intent2.putExtra("kind", mail_type);
}
intent2.putExtra("id", id);
intent2.putExtra("from_which_type", 0);
intent2.putExtra("from_message_show", true);
intent2.putExtra("message_id", id);
intent2.putExtra("list_type", type);
intent2.putExtra("sender_title", sender);
intent2.putExtra("mail_type", mail_type);
intent2.putExtra("attached_files", file_name);
startActivity(intent2);
return true;
```

и вот как его получаю:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        extras = intent.getExtras();

        adapter = new AttachedFileAdapter(mNames);
        draft_files = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files");
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
                //mNames.add(String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files")))); //new ArrayList is only needed if you absolutely need an ArrayList
                mNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files")));
                mNames.add(Arrays.toString(getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files")));

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                array = new JsonArray();
                //getImages();

                Log.w("MY_TAG", Arrays.toString(getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files")));
            } else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                array = new JsonArray();
            }
        } else {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            array = new JsonArray();
        }
```

как можно понять (я надеюсь код понятный) из кода, что у меня при написании нового письма все нормально, и файлы прикрепляются нормально и отображаются тоже нормально. А вот отображение пересланных с активити названий файлов почему то не добавляются в список и я не могу понять в чем проблема. Вот как я список формирую в форме написания сообщений:

```
private void getImages() {
        mNames.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
            if (extras != null) {
                if (extras.containsKey("attached_files")) {
                    mNames.add(Arrays.toString(draft_files));
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", Arrays.toString(draft_files));
                } else {
                    mNames.add(object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.w("MY_TAG", String.valueOf(mNames));
                }
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

возможно я не очень понятно рассказал суть проблемы, если что постараюсь написать более развернуто вдруг будет не очень понятно что я имею в виду) Заранее спасибо за помощь и ценные советы.

### update

вот только что заметил что иногда получается отобразить список, но он почему то дублирует каждый элемент и это не правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не очень понятный, но на взгляд:

1. в первом куске intent2.putExtra("attached_files", file_name); file_name - это строка или массив строк?
2. draft_files = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("attached_files"); зачем второй вызов getIntent

В общем повнимательнее посмотрите, где у вас массив, а где строка и что куда вы передаете, для данного случая, а вообще почему бы вам не использовать БД для передачи данных между активити? Также есть вариант с Parcelable, не очень хорошо передавать такую кучу параметров через intent. Используйте какой-нибудь clean architecture подход с использованием БД и передавайте все через БД (используйте orm для того, чтобы упростить себе работу с БД). (MVP/MVVM, но можете обойтись и без clean architecture, просто каким-нибудь orm) Тогда вы сможете хранить объект своего письма и связанные с ним объекты файлов в БД и в intent передавать только id объекта письма, а по нему делать запрос к БД.